# run qt designer/qt assistant with commands designer/assitant respectively

Tags: qt

I'm used to an environment where I run the qt designer/qt assistant simply typing designer/assitant in the terminal. 
I am talking about qt 4.
I've been installing packages such as qtcreator and qt4-default, but I get this:

```
~$ assistant
assistant: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/assistant': No such file or directory
~$ designer
designer: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/designer': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you installed Qt4 from Ubuntu official repo? Could you add output of `sudo updatedb; locate bin/assistant`